# How to optimize join when search in categories

Tags: mysql, categories

I have a table with items:

```
CREATE TABLE `ost_content` (
  `uid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` enum('media','serial','season','series') NOT NULL,
  `alias` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `views` mediumint(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ratings_count` enum('0','1','2','4','5') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ratings_sum` mediumint(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `upload_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `conversion_status` enum('converting','error','success','announcement') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'converting',
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_uid_type` (`uid`,`type`),
  KEY `idx_type` (`type`),
  KEY `idx_upload_date DESC` (`upload_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And table, that connect items with categories:

```
CREATE TABLE `ost_categories2media` (
  `categories2media_id` mediumint(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `categories2media_category_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `categories2media_uid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`categories2media_id`),
  KEY `categories2media_media_id` (`categories2media_uid`),
  KEY `categories2media_category_id` (`categories2media_category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=501114 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Than, I executing query:

```
SELECT
    c1.uid,
    c1.alias,
    c1.type,
    c1.views,
    c1.upload_date,
    c1.ratings_sum,
    c1.ratings_count,
    c1.conversion_status
FROM
    ost_content c1
LEFT JOIN ost_categories2media c2m ON c2m.categories2media_uid = c1.uid
WHERE
    c2m.categories2media_category_id = '53'
AND c1.conversion_status IN ('success', 'announcement')
AND c1.type IN ('serial', 'media')
ORDER BY
    c1.upload_date DESC
LIMIT 16, 16
```

It executing slow, categories2media_category_id check many rows:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                          | key                          | key_len | ref                             | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c2m   | ref    | categories2media_media_id,categories2media_category_id | categories2media_category_id | 2       | const                           | 32076 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c1    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_uid_type,idx_type                          | PRIMARY                      | 3       | uakino.c2m.categories2media_uid |     1 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

How I can optimize or rewrite this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql indexes are like cooks, too many of them aren't very useful because mysql uses only one index per table. Let's look at `ost_categories2media`,
That's three separate indexes on three columns. You are better off with two indexes like this.

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`categories2media_id`),
  KEY `categories2media_media_id` (`categories2media_uid`,`categories2media_category_id`)
```

Now mysql no longer has to decide between an index on `categories2media_uid` or `categories2media_category_id` it has an index that covers both!

Looking at your ost_content table we see

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_uid_type` (`uid`,`type`),
  KEY `idx_type` (`type`),
  KEY `idx_upload_date DESC` (`upload_date`)
```

Some of these indexes are a bit redundant. Any query that filters on the `uid` field can use the PK while any query that filters on `type` can use `idx_type` that means `idx_uid_type` is there just to enforce the uniqueness. But we can make it more usefull like this:

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_uid_type` (`type`,`uid`),
  KEY `idx_upload_date DESC` (`upload_date`)
```

We've got rid of one index! that ought to make your indexes a lot faster. You still have an index on upload_date that isn't used in this particulary query. So how about a composite index for that?

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_uid_type` (`type`,`uid`),
  KEY `idx_upload_date DESC` (`uid`,`upload_date`)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the `LEFT JOIN` is not necessary.  So, you can write the query as:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM ost_content c JOIN
     ost_categories2media c2m
     ON c2m.categories2media_uid = c.uid
WHERE c2m.categories2media_category_id = '53' AND
      c.conversion_status IN ('success', 'announcement') AND
      c.type IN ('serial', 'media')
ORDER BY c.upload_date DESC
LIMIT 16, 16;
```

Unfortunately, your conditions on the content table are not simple `=` conditions.  If they were, and index on `ost_content(conversion_status, type, uid)` would be recommended.  This might still be the better option.

Another option is to go the other way:  An index on `ost_categories2media(categories2media_category_id, categories2media_uid)`.

You might find that the first composite index and this query work best:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM ((SELECT c.*
       FROM ost_content c JOIN
            ost_categories2media c2m
            ON c2m.categories2media_uid = c.uid
       WHERE c2m.categories2media_category_id = '53' AND
             c.conversion_status = 'success' AND
             c.type IN ('serial', 'media')
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT c.*
       FROM ost_content c JOIN
            ost_categories2media c2m
            ON c2m.categories2media_uid = c.uid
       WHERE c2m.categories2media_category_id = '53' AND
             c.conversion_status = 'announcement' AND
             c.type IN ('serial', 'media')
      ) 
     ) c
ORDER BY c.upload_date DESC
LIMIT 16, 16;
```

This looks more complicated, but each subquery can take advantage of the index, so it might have improved performance.